# ValueError: X has 2 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting 321 features as input

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I was making a simple RandomForest Classifier Model

My hobbies classification dataset looks like this :

```
    Name              Category
0   Acroyoga           general
1   Tennis             sports
2   Aerial silk        general
3   Sociology          Academic
4   Amateur radio      general
```

1. I split it into test and training
2. Encoded usin OneHotEncoder
3. Trained it using `model = RandomForectClassifier()` and `model.fit(X_train)`

It performed very well on the test dataset with an accuracy of 100%

Now, I wanted the model to predict a custom input  I give.

So, I did this :

```
my_test = [ 'ML','Cricket']

test = pd.DataFrame(my_test, columns = ['testing'])

a = pd.get_dummies(test, columns = ['Duh'])

model.predict(a)
```

But it is giving this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-8c4c6395f80e> in <module>
----> 1 model.predict(a)

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in predict(self, X)
    628             The predicted classes.
    629         """
--> 630         proba = self.predict_proba(X)
    631 
    632         if self.n_outputs_ == 1:

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in predict_proba(self, X)
    672         check_is_fitted(self)
    673         # Check data
--> 674         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
    675 
    676         # Assign chunk of trees to jobs

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X)
    420         check_is_fitted(self)
    421 
--> 422         return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
    423 
    424     @property

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
    400         """Validate the training data on predict (probabilities)."""
    401         if check_input:
--> 402             X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr",
    403                                     reset=False)
    404             if issparse(X) and (X.indices.dtype != np.intc or

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    435 
    436         if check_params.get('ensure_2d', True):
--> 437             self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
    438 
    439         return out

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    363 
    364         if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
--> 365             raise ValueError(
    366                 f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    367                 f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input.")

**ValueError: X has 2 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting 321 features as input.**
```

Comment: Can you please provide a few rows of what is in your `X_train` dataset? It appears that the number of columns in X_train is 321, which will clearly break when you try to predict on a feature vector of length 2 as you show here.

Comment: @TCArlen The confusing part is that len(X_train) returns 226

Comment: Can you provide sme other way on how I could predict my custom input

Comment: It is because you use two different one hot encoders for training set and test set. In your training set, `X_train` has 321 one hot encoded features. In your test set, `my_test` has only 2 features 'ML' and 'Cricket'. Just because it is 0 and 1 doesn't mean you can predict it without aligning the dimension. To fix this, you should use the same `sklearn` `OneHotEncoder` to transform both datasets.

Comment: @jasonwong Thanks a lot. That clears it up. However, do you know how I can do this ?

Comment: Please see the `OneHotEncoder` example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html